# Package 'mysql-community-client-plugins' has no installation candidate

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu

I am trying to install `mysqlclient` using pip and getting red text, saying there is no config.h file. I started fixing that and stucked on installing `libmysqlcppconn-dev` on Ubuntu 20. Terminal says

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlcppconn-dev : Depends: libmysqlcppconn8-2 (= 8.0.27-1ubuntu18.04) but it is not going to be installed
```

After trying `sudo apt install -f libmysqlcppconn8-2` I see

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlcppconn8-2 : Depends: mysql-community-client-plugins but it is not installable
```

How can I fix that? Thanks everybody.